# Forced SSL in htaccess going to only the home page

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have recently added an SSL to my sites. I have added the code to the .htaccess file to force the https. The issue is that my external links that go to pages within the site are now being redirected to the homepage. The code I am using is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.watsonelec.com%1 [R,L]
```

I think the issue is in the last line, as the rule is telling it to redirect to the homepage. What I can't seem to find is a rule that will say for it to go to the URL provided in the link but give it an https instead of the HTTP.

I did do a search for this topic, but all the code I found was similar to what I already had. Thank you for all your help.

## Update

I have two sites I am trying to work this out for, watsonenerysolutions.com and watsonelec.com.

When I tried

```
RewriteOptions InheritDownBefore
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.watsonenergysolutions.com/$1 [R,L]
```

It still sent to the homepage

When I tried

```
RewriteOptions InheritDownBefore
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.watsonenergysolution.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

I received an error message that said Safari can't open the page "https://www.watsonenergysolutions.com/index.php" because Safari can't find server "www.watsonenergysolutions.com"

Answer (score 0):

`%N` backreferences are what you match in `RewriteCond`'s. In your case, it is empty. That's why anything is going to the homepage.

You need to use `$1` or `%{REQUEST_URI}`, both rules below are equivalent (the second may be faster because you don't -re-match unnecessarily)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.watsonelec.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^ https://www.watsonelec.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Note 1: `%{REQUEST_URI}` value **always** begins with a leading `/`, while what you can match in a `RewriteRule` **never** begins with a leading `/`

Note 2: `R` flag uses a `302` redirect by default. Maybe you'll want to use a `301` (`[R=301,L]`)

Comment: I tried to respond with a comment, but my response was too long so I added it as an answer.

Comment: First thing, I see `RewriteOptions InheritDownBefore` which means you have a hierarchy of htaccess files. Maybe some parent/child rules interfer ? Also, what are the rules you tried and didn't work ?

Comment: No, I really don't have a hierarchy of .htaccess files. I inherited these sites and while I haven't seen any additional .htaccess files, I wanted to be sure that this one was being used so I added the Rewrite option. As far as other rules I have tried, I used RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.watsonelec.com%1 [R,L]. It was something I found online. It also didn't work.

Comment: `InheritDownBefore` means children htaccess files will inherit those rules **but** parent (current) rules are executed first. In your case, you can remove it because it's useless. Sorry, I wanted to ask for `urls` you tried and didn't work with the rule (the first or the other) I gave you

Comment: I tried the rules you gave me with the URL www.watsonenergysolutions.com. Since it didn't work I didn't try it with the www.watsonelec.com site. I will remove the rewrite opt.

Comment: Indeed, I analyzed http headers sent by your server and it seems that there is a rule *somewhere* (even in your php code, maybe) to remove `index.php` from url. It may interfer with the rule I gave you if you're using it right. That's a good start for investigation

Comment: Thanks - I'll start to look into that and post what I find.